# Allow Local Computers to Access Any Port in Windows Firewall

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, firewall

I want to enable any computers on my local network to connect to each other directly. I had to use this command in PowerShell to add a new rule to the receiving computers:

```ps
New-NetFirewallRule -Name AllowLocalComputers -DisplayName 'AllowLocalComputers' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol ANY -Action Allow -Profile ANY -RemoteAddress 192.168.0.0-192.168.0.255
```

Is there any security concern in doing this? The computers are connected to the internet and I want to ensure I'm only opening them up to local connections.

Edit, for more background:

I'm running a hardware monitoring program (LibreHardwareMonitor) on various render clients (a bunch of laptops I have accumulated over the years) which expose the CPU temperatures over a port. I could only access them from my main machine if I opened port 8085 on the firewall.

Comment: I want to enable any computers on my local network to connect to each other directly. I had to use this command in PowerShell to add a new rule to the receiving computers:    ...  I have never had to do this to permit one computer on my local network to connect to another computer on my local network.

Comment: @John, I'm running a hardware monitoring program (LibreHardwareMonitor) on various render clients which expose the CPU temperatures over a port. I could only access them from my main machine if I opened that port on the firewall.

Comment: You should clarify your question with this information. I would not ever have guessed this.

Comment: As long as PS remoting is enabled in your enterprise, there is no rationale that I can think of for you to do this FW setting. You just invoke a command on a remote system(s). You can set up PS Remoting in workgroup mode to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @John, thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: @jippyjoe4 If you trust all your local computers, know they won't be used by malicious actors, have endpoint security on all the workstations, then it can be just fine and secure but you need to understand the risk. If you can determine the explicit ports by all legit software and functionality you need to share between the machines on the subnet and your operations, it'd be much better to perhaps just all those ports on any protocol. If you have a control server or workstation that collects the data, it may make better sense to allow all and the all ports with just the IP of that machine.